# Trying to merge multiple tsv files in R based on two common columns

Tags: r, csv, merge

I have a number of different tsv files, each one has the same column names and the same number of rows. I would like to merge the files, but based on two specific columns, as illustrated below (example of first lines of one tsv file):

```
#chrom chromStart  chromEnd           gene_id score strand         name exonic_length num_reads num_reads_fw
1      1  100250296 100250441 ENSG00000201491.1     .      -     RNU4-75P           146         0            0
2      1  100257218 100257309 ENSG00000202254.1     .      +        Y_RNA            92         0            0
3      1  100295021 100295093 ENSG00000252226.1     .      +   AL451051.1            73         0            0
```

My ultimate goal is:
A) Merge all the tsv files, but keeping only two specific columns, namely gene_id and num_reads

B) After merging, transpose the resulted data frame in order to have the tsv filenames as column names,
gene_id as the rownames and the actual content would be the numeric column num_reads.

An "artificial" example of the desired final output (from another example), would be the following data frame/matrix:

## where the column names are the relative names of my tsv files, the numeric values are the num_reads column for all the rows and the rownames are similar to the gene_id, the second column that i would like to isolate:

```
head(assay(rse_gene))
                   SRR2079883 SRR2079884 SRR2079882 SRR2079885 SRR2079881 SRR2079880
ENSG00000000003.14     168731     180764     153611     171413     178689     163379
ENSG00000000005.5        1035       2828       1200       3059        676       1146
ENSG00000000419.12      59444      56188      84757      57178     103568      87674
ENSG00000000457.13      89775      89363     105319      84121     108518     102589
ENSG00000000460.16      51868      55312     153095      58828     154572     147016
ENSG00000000938.12        539        606        516        407       1337        624
```

I tried initially the following approach:

```
library(readr)
df <- list.files(full.names=T)%>% 
  lapply(read_tsv)%>%
  bind_rows
```

as additionally:

```
library(tidyverse);library(data.table)

listGeneFiles <- list.files(".",pattern=".tsv",full.names = TRUE)

dt.gene <- map(listGeneFiles, ~fread(.x, select=c(4,8))) %>%
reduce(left_join)
```

but no approach gave the intended result. Also, a potential issue might be that the first column has a # character as you can see..

Any suggestions or ideas would be grateful !!

Best,

Efstathios

Comment: So what's the intended result? Will all the files look like this one? It would be easier to follow if you included more than one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
# function to read in a tsv and add the file name as a column
customized_read_tsv <- function(file){
    read_tsv(file) %>%
        mutate(fileName = file)
}

list.files(full.names = TRUE) %>% # list all the files
    lapply(customized_read_tsv) %>% # read them all in with our custom function
    reduce(bind_rows) %>% # stack them all on top of each other
    select(gene_id, fileName, num_reads) %>% # select the correct columns
    pivot_wider(names_from = fileName, values_from = num_reads) # and switch from "long format" to "wide format"
```

One addition: This reads in all the files in the **working directory** which usually contains other files as well, e.g. the R-script you are actually running or an Rproj file. I would recommend to put the tsv files in a sub directory and then do something like `list.files(path = "~/sourceFiles", full.names = TRUE)`.